# Mongoose - add global method to all models

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Simple question:

How can I add static methods to my models in Mongoose, that applies to every model instead of just one?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So you have one static method that (eg) your User, Blog, Comment, and Alert models all share without any differences in implementation?

The de facto way to apply behavior to multiple different models in Mongoose is through plugins, and you can do a global plugin. I'll stick to traditional syntax, but if you want to use ES6 imports and exports feel free.

```
// ./models/plugins/echo.js
module.exports = function echoPlugin(schema, options) {
  schema.statics.echo = function(){ console.log('Echo'); }
}
```

That defines a plugin which could be applied to a single schema like so:

```
userSchema.plugin(require('./plugins/echo'));
```

Or alternatively to all models in your project like so:

```
// somewhere in your app startup code
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var echoPlugin = require('./models/plugins/echo');

mongoose.plugin(echoPlugin);
```

Comment: `mongoose.plugin(...)` was exactly what I needed!